# Namaz ruling for flight attendants?

Tags: salat

Asslamualaikum.
I'm working with Qatar Airways. I stay in Doha, Qatar. 
Every after 1 or 2 days I leave Doha and go for a flight ( another destination). I stay there for 1 or 2 days and come back to Doha.
I'm not sure whether Qasar namaz rule apply for me while I'm in the flight or when I'm staying in the hotel for 1 day. And do I need to perform full prayer when I am back to Doha??? 
Kindly guide me on this please

Comment: @Medi1Saif. I agree. That's my question I'm a working, that is my profession I'm not a traveller. And one more thing I have asked in mu previous question is - can I shorten all my prayer until I stay in other country??

Comment: @Shaz_174 it's my profession. Am I a traveller?  Can I shorten my prayer until I stay in other country??

Answer (score 2):

Wa'alaykum al-salam,

I will try to answer this question to the best of my knowledge.

If Doha, Qatar is your place of residence, then as soon as you leave the city boundaries and intend to travel more than 88km, for matters which do not involve disobedience, you will be considered a traveller.

A difference of opinion arises (when being considered as a traveller) depending on how long you intend to stay at a location; as you state 1/2 days, you are considered a traveller in **all madhhabs**.

As a traveller, it is permissible for you to perform qasr on your flight (as long as you are outside the boundaries of your place of residence). Likewise, as soon as you re-enter your residential city's boundaries, (in this case: Doha) then you will be obliged to perform all prayers fully.

I hope that answers the question; if anything I have stated is incorrect please correct me.

All of the above legislations, *unless stated otherwise*, are in accordance with the **Hanafi madhhab**. If you would like rulings for other madhhabs, please let me know and I will try my best to find them.

Edits:
*1/1/20*
I have found a fatwa in relation to what @Medi1Saif was mentioning for sailors:

> It is necessary to complete full salah if the traveller ... is a
>   sailor whose family is with him and he does not intend residency in
>   any land (b: since his journey is not interrupted in addition that he
>   does not move away from his land and family. It is the same for a
>   donkey driver, an animal herder, the Sultan's messenger, and the like.
>   (m: Modern examples would include people who have jobs where the
>   travel itself is part of the job, such as people who work on
>   airplanes, buses, trains, and ships. But someone who travels 81 km or
>   more to get to work should be entitled to shorten. And Allah knows
>   best.)

I found this in some Hanbali fiqh archive. As per this, the principle that stands out to me is that the traveller **does not intend residency in any land**. Thence, I would say if @Aarefa considers Doha to be her permanent place of residence (i.e. residing with family and belongings without having a definite intention of relocating), travelling to other destinations under the above conditions: @Aarefa will be allowed to shorten salah. In my opinion, the situation is synonymous to a normal citizen who resides in Doha and travels every few days fulfilling the conditions of a traveller; merely travelling for work.

However, I would like to highlight that I am no scholar and it would be safer to post an enquiry on some fatwa/q&a site; I am not completely confident upon this matter.

*4/1/20*
I have just asked an Islamic Scholar and as per the Hanafi school of thought, it is permissible to shorten even if it is part of your job (under the above conditions).

Comment: I guess the point which needs to be discussed is whether a person who 8s traveling in his profession can be considered as a traveler or not and whether he should pray full prayers or shortened ones. What you've answered is the general case about the difference between residents and travelers. I think the matter is a bit different as I recall reading a fatwa asked by a sailor.

Comment: I see, however, I assume that it would not apply here as the poster has stated that they stay in Doha; similarly, I recall many legislations in regard to those who travel far for work (>100km) and the ruling given is that it is permissible to shorten: the only conditions for a traveller what I have written above and so I assume as long as they are fulfilled one is considered a traveller and the rulings of a traveller apply.

Comment: @Medi1Saif, I have edited in some additional information in the post; please look over it.

Comment: I have just asked an Islamic Scholar and as per the Hanafi school of thought, it is permissible to shorten even if it is part of your job (under the above conditions).